# SQL Server 2012: left join multiple select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to find retail outlets that worked in May or stopped working in June.

I have a SQL query like:

```
select * 
from
    (select a.OL_id [Kod], d.Year, d.Month, OLRegion_name, OLDistrict_name, OLCntArea_name, OLCity_name, a.RM_name, a.DSM_Name, a.Supervisor_name, a.MerchName, SUM(s.SaleDal) [Sales]
    from DW_Cube_Area a
    join DW_Cube_Fact_Sale s on a.Area_Id=s.Area_Id
    join DW_Cube_Time d on d.Date_Id=s.Date_Id
    join DW_Cube_SKU p on s.SKU_Id=p.SKU_Id
    where d.Date between '20180501' and '20180531'
    and a.StartDate between '20180501' and '20180531'
    and a.PID=0 and s.PID=0
    and p.ProdGroupName Not Like 'Напої'
    and p.UnitName  Like 'кег'
    group by  d.Year, d.Month, a.OL_id, a.RM_name, a.DSM_Name, a.Supervisor_name, a.MerchName, OLRegion_name, OLDistrict_name, OLCntArea_name, OLCity_name
    having ABS(SUM(s.SaleDal))>0.1) tb1
left join
    (select a.OL_id [Kod], d.Year, d.Month, OLRegion_name, OLDistrict_name, OLCntArea_name, OLCity_name, a.RM_name, a.DSM_Name, a.Supervisor_name, a.MerchName, SUM(s.SaleDal) [Sales]
    from DW_Cube_Area a
    join DW_Cube_Fact_Sale s on a.Area_Id=s.Area_Id
    join DW_Cube_Time d on d.Date_Id=s.Date_Id
    join DW_Cube_SKU p on s.SKU_Id=p.SKU_Id
    where d.Date between '20180601' and '20180630'
    and a.StartDate between '20180601' and '20180630'
    and a.PID=0 and s.PID=0
    and p.ProdGroupName Not Like 'Напої'
    and p.UnitName  Like 'кег'
    group by  d.Year, d.Month, a.OL_id, a.RM_name, a.DSM_Name, a.Supervisor_name, a.MerchName, OLRegion_name, OLDistrict_name, OLCntArea_name, OLCity_name
    having ABS(SUM(s.SaleDal))>0.1) tb2
on 
    t1.Kod = t2.Kod
where 
    t2.Kod is null
```

When I execute this query, the error result is:

**The multi-part identifier "t1.Kod" could not be bound.**

**The multi-part identifier "t2.Kod" could not be bound.**

Why?

If i divide the query into 2 individual query, it run ok.

Comment: Your aliases are `tb1`/`tb2`, not `t1`/`t2`.

Comment: use tb1 as tb2 instead of t1 and t2

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. Facepalm. How can I be so inattentive?
I spent 2 hours looking for a solution yesterday.
Thank you. Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want more easily using conditional aggregation:

```
select a.OL_id [Kod], d.Year, d.Month, OLRegion_name, OLDistrict_name, OLCntArea_name, OLCity_name, a.RM_name, a.DSM_Name, a.Supervisor_name, a.MerchName,
       sum(case when d.Date between '20180501' and '20180531' and a.StartDate between '20180501' and '20180531'
                then s.SaleDal else 0
           end) as sales_201805,
       sum(case when d.Date between '20180601' and '20180630' and a.StartDate between '20180601' and '20180630'
                then s.SaleDal else 0
           end) as sales_201806
from DW_Cube_Area a join
     DW_Cube_Fact_Sale s
     on a.Area_Id = s.Area_Id join
     DW_Cube_Time d
     on d.Date_Id = s.Date_Id join
     DW_Cube_SKU p
     on s.SKU_Id = p.SKU_Id
where a.PID = 0 and s.PID = 0 and
      p.ProdGroupName Not Like 'Напої' and
     p.UnitName  Like 'кег'
group by d.Year, d.Month, a.OL_id, a.RM_name, a.DSM_Name, a.Supervisor_name, a.MerchName, OLRegion_name, OLDistrict_name, OLCntArea_name, OLCity_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your query does not work correctly.  
1) it unloads all **OL_id** since 2009 (it turns out more than 2 million rows).   
2) columns **sales_201806** and **sales_201805** are filled only 0.    

The first half of my query returns 22000 rows and the second half of my query returns 24000 rows. The result should be about 5000 rows that were in the first request but not in the second.

Answer (score 0):

aliases should  tb1/tb2, not t1/t2

```
on 
    tb1.Kod = tb2.Kod
where 
    tb2.Kod is null
```

Now everything works.